# Facebook publish actions - Values from preview object are taken when publishing

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

Ok I am trying to publish an action on facebook from my mobile game.

I have set up an object (say "picture") and an action (say "draw")
I have set up an external web page whose meta data describes the object "picture"

Now I  send a post request from my game with parameters

- access_token = token
- picture = the external link of the object

The action is published.  But not with the values I give in my external page's meta data. The action published has the values which i gave to the PREVIEW OBJECT of the object "picture"

**In short, the action published takes its values (like og:title, og:image, etc) from the PREVIEW OBJECT of "picture" and not from the external link's meta data.**

Hope that makes sense.

I'm pretty sure the solution would be something really simple, but I can't figure out what the problem is.  Please help.

Comment: I'm seeing exactly the same issue in my Facebook app. Did you ever solve it? I tried to set dynamic parameters in the "Edit Preview Object" form (under developers.facebook.com/apps/YOUR_APP_ID/opengraph/object_type/YOR_OBJECT_ID) but it's not accepting things like {og:title}, {og:picture}, etc....Any tips/ideas?

Comment: still having this issue...any tips @SatheeshJM ?

Comment: I THINK i solved this prob. I dumped that project, so don't actually remember. Will have a look and post a solution when I have the time.  Bump me if I forget to come back. :)

Comment: Still waiting for your super cool answer @SatheeshJM :)