# Publish Action similar to Draw My Thing

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

In the Facebook game DRAW MY THING,   once the user draws a picture, the action is published to the timeline **along with the drawn picture**

Is it possible to do the same from a mobile game which has been integrated with Facebook?
If yes, how do we do it?

P.S    I have spent a lot of time, trying to get this working.  I got some problems (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10643748/facebook-publish-actions-values-from-preview-object-are-taken-when-publishing) so I am starting from scratch.  Hence this post. 
So please do not post comments saying stuff like "show proof of what you have done till now" and what-not.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You've started from the scratch, so what? Have you tried to read documentation? http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/